# How do I prove this for all binary trees?

Tags: induction, trees

Ok, so here is my question.

**For a binary tree B,**

**count of nodes is nodeCount(B)**

**count of leaves is leafCount(B)**

**count of half nodes is halfnodeCount(B)  (Half nodes are nodes that have just one child).**

**P(B) is given by nodeCount(B) = 2 x leafCount(B) + halfnodeCount(B) - 1**

**Using mathematical induction, prove that P(B) holds for all binary trees.**

I was able to prove the base case, when the tree has just one node, and no leaves or half nodes.

That is, nodeCount(B) = 1, leafCount(B) = 1, halfnodeCount(B) = 0

2 x leafCount(B) + halfnodeCount(B) - 1

= (2 x 1) + 0 - 1

= 2 + 0 - 1

= 1

= nodeCount(B)

Now I need to assume that P(B) is true for a tree B of k nodes, then prove that P(B) also holds for B with k+1 nodes.

Please help, I am not sure how to go about this.

Comment: What is a "node that has just one leaf"?  Did you mean a "node that has just one child"?

Comment: In any event, I don't think you want to induct on the number of nodes.  Prove it by recursion (what some books call "structural induction").  Given a binary tree, if the root has two children and the theorem is true for the left subtree and the right subtree, prove it's true for the tree.  Since the theorem is not true for an empty tree, you also have to deal with the case where the root has only one child in a similar way.

Comment: @saulspatz

Thanks, I have made the correction.

Comment: Hint: Consider a tree $B$ with $k+1$ nodes, where $k$ is at least $1$. Color one leaf node red and the rest of the nodes green, calling the green tree (with $k$ nodes) $B'$. By induction, $P(B')$ holds. Now $B$ has one more node that $B'$. How can the leaf and half-node counts of $B$ and $B'$ differ?

Comment: @SteveKass

Thank you, that makes sense. But when I assume it is true for a tree with k nodes, I also need to express the terms 'leafCount' and 'halfnodeCount' in term of k. How do I do that?

Comment: You don’t have to do that. More hint: If $B$ has $k+1$ nodes, and you remove a leaf node $v$ to get $B'$ (for which you are assuming the proposition is true), then there are two cases: a) The removed $v$ had no sibling, so in $B'$, $v$’s parent is now a leaf and leafCount($B$) = leafCount($B'$). (Removing $v$ removed one leaf but created one new leaf.) Also, in $B$, $v$’s parent was a half-node and is no longer, so halfnodeCount($B'$) = halfnodeCount($B$) - 1. The other case, b), is where $v$ had a sibling. What happens to leafCount and halfnodeCount when you delete a leaf with a sibling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving what I put in comments to an answer (answering “how to go about this?” without providing a complete proof):

You can use regular induction for this. You proved that $P(1)$ holds, so you need to prove that $P(k) \implies P(k+1)$ when $k\ge 1$.

Let $B$ be a tree with $k+1$ nodes.

$B$ has at least one leaf, so choose one ($v$) and remove it to obtain $B'$.

Consider these two cases:

Case 1: The removed leaf $v$ was an only child.
Case 2: The removed leaf $v$ had a sibling.

Case 1: In the smaller tree $B'$, $v$’s parent is now a leaf, because $v$ was an only child. Therefore leafCount($B$) = leafCount($B'$). (Removing $v$ removed one leaf but created one new leaf.) Also, in $B$ $v$’s parent was a half-node and is no longer, so halfnodeCount($B'$) = halfnodeCount}($B$) - 1.

Therefore $2\times$leafCount($B$) + halfnodeCount($B$) - 1 = 2 leafCount($B'$) + (halfnodeCount($B'$)+1) - 1 = $k+1$ (which is what was to be shown).

Case 2: See if you can do this similarly.

Comment: Thanks a ton! 

But when I try to do it similarly for case 2, this is what I get:

If the removed leaf had a sibling, then leafCount(B') = leafCount(B) - 1 and halfnodeCount(B') = halfnodeCount(B) + 1

So 2 x leafCount(B) + halfnodeCount(B) - 1 = 2 x (leafCount(B') + 1) + halfnodeCount(B') - 1 - 1
= 2 x leafCount(B') + 2 + halfnodeCount(B')  - 2
= 2 x leafCount(B') + halfnodeCount(B')
= k+1

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct!